# DAO Governance Off Chain

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, defi, dao, off-chain

What are good methods for DAO decisions to be implemented off chain? If a company is looking to start a DAO to manage a specific centralized service (say a website, manufacturing plant, etc) through decentralized means, how can DAO votes be implemented off chain on that centralized service? Are there enforcement mechanisms that will work?

Answer (score 1):

For what I know, the best way is to enroll the executive party in the Dao. I will provide financial incentive to deliver and they will be paid in crypto. If they don't want or can't enroll their company in a Dao, they can have an interface but the risk is centralisation.

Comment: If the executive is in the DAO, what ensures that the executive does what the DAO votes for them to do off-chain? What would the repercussion be if the executive does not follow through?

Comment: They should not have the findings and even lose part of their money (Dao token) si they are incentivised not to cheat or underperform.

Comment: This also requires that the Dao contains some verifiers who will be checking the work (it can be any Dao stakeholder in case of a virtual work like a website) but it can be expert companies that are also enrolled in the Dao and provide their verification services to the Dao and get paid with the token.

Answer (score 0):

One way is with executors like discussed above, but another option is to have votes off-chain and then use an oracle to push the values on-chain.  Gnosis multisigs (via their Zodiac tool pack (https://github.com/gnosis/zodiac ) have a a few options).

I know [tellor](https://www.tellor.io) works with them in this manner, where you have a snapshot vote off-chain and then the oracle brings it back on-chain to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Great questions @YigalZamora ,

this is one way to do it :

Perform activities off-chain and after a decision is finalised, write the output of that on chain. This works similar to a soft fork or investment allocation. Pls read more here abt the benefits and risks:

- https://www.coindesk.com/learn/2016/06/25/understanding-the-dao-attack/